# Cygwin installation says permission Denied when Downloading from the mirrir sites?

Tags: cygwin, mingw

fatal: Can't open C:\Users\Home\Documents/http%3a%2f%2fmirror.clarkson.edu%2fcygwin%2f/noarch/release/base-cygwin/base-cygwin-3.8-1.tar.xz.tmp for writing: Permission denied
Ending cygwin install

I tried re reinstalling it says the same ?

And Mingw is blocked source-forge.net is anyone has another site to sownload ?

Comment: who is blocking the download ? Your Antivirus by chance ?

Comment: I assume you downloaded setuo_x86-64.exe from https://cygwin.com/ and execute it. It will ask several questions. One will ask for a cache directory.. that folder must be writable. A folder in you Downloads folder like cygwin_cache is a good choice. Use the directory open dialog to browse to this spot, click new folder and enter a name. If you don't know how to answer any question in setup ACCEPT THE DEFAULT. You can picked a reasonable choice for mirror.